# Rail spacing & Child proofing a deck

Tags: deck, child-safety

For a deck to be considered child proofed, what is the recommended spacing between the rails?

Comment: You should mention where you are - some countries have codes about this sort of thing, and you'd want the relevant code for your area.

Comment: You also need to follow regulations on height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a google search and turned up one [recommendation](http://www.safebeginnings.com/Docs/Library/How-To/childproofing_balconies.asp) for a maximum 4 inch spacing. That sounds right to me, and is in accordance with the International Residential Code for One- and Two-Family Dwellings.

> R312.3 Opening limitations. Required guards shall not have openings
>   from the walking surface to the required guard height which allow
>   passage of a sphere 4 inches (102 mm) in diameter.

Answer (score 1):

Less than 4" is most typical code, but if you want to be sure check with your local code office. Personally, I usually go with 3.5" because it's easy to use a 2x4" as a spacer, and it's plenty under 4".